# How do you add values to an angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

I am having a heck of a time getting what should be simple to work.

I am using ui-router and ngResource. I have a factory that returns the resource.

When I go to the add state the controller has the resource injected and then I do code like:

```
vm.member = new memberResource(object);
```

the object has values I want to default in for a new member. However, when the form binds, none of those values are showing in the form.

I even tried doing vm.member.property = 'value' after the above line and that didn't work either.

Here is part of my router config:

```
  .state('member', {
        url: '/member/:id',
        templateUrl: 'app/memberdetail.html',
        controller: 'MemberDetail',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('member.add', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'app/memberdetail.html',
        controller: 'MemberCreate',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

Any hints as to what I am doing wrong. Is the problem sharing the template maybe?

I also use this same resource for the member list and to edit members which all seems to work fine.

Needless to say, this is quite frustrating.

Here is the view:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<form name="memberEdit" ng-submit="memberEdit.$valid && vm.save()" novalidate>
    <div ng-show="vm.member.id" class="form-group">
        <label for="memberNumber">Member Number</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.member.memberNumber" name="memberNumber" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.member.firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.member.lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" ng-model="vm.member.dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter date of birth">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailAddress">Email</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="vm.member.emailAddress" name="emailAddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cellNumber">Cell Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.member.cellNumber" ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" name="cellNumber" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="memberType">Membership Type</label>
        <select ng-model="vm.member.memberType" name="memberType" class="form-control">
            <option>Individual</option>
            <option>Family</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-hide="vm.member.memberType != 'Family'" required>
        <label for="primaryFamilyMember">Primary Family Member</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.member.primaryFamilyMember" name="primaryFamilyMember" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter primary family member numer" ng-required="vm.member.memberType == 'Family'">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="memberLevel">Member Level</label>
        <select ng-model="vm.member.memberLevel" name="memberLevel" class="form-control">
            <option>Blue</option>
            <option>Silver</option>
            <option>Gold</option>
            <option>Platinum</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfExpiry">Expiration Date</label>
        <input type="text" id="dateOfExpiry" ng-model="vm.member.dateOfExpiry" name="dateOfExpiry" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd">

    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input ng-model="vm.member.isActive" name="isActive" type="checkbox">
            Active
        </label>
    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="memberEdit.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
function MemberCreate($state, $stateParams, memberResource) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.member = new memberResource({
        firstName: 'Test',
        isActive: false,
        memberLevel: 'Gold',
        memberType: 'Individual',
        dateOfExpiry: new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0),
        cellNumber: '4015551212'
    });

    vm.save = save;

    function save() {
        vm.member.$save(function () {
            // TODO: Toster alert
            $state.go('member', { id: vm.member.id });
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: I don't think your state has much to do with the problem that you're having.  Even so, we'd need to see some of your controller and view logic. When you say "when the form binds," what form do you mean?

Comment: ^^Yeah, what does the view look like?

Comment: added the view. @MikeL the view is bound to vm.member items, but they don't show the default values I am using.

Comment: What do you show when you try to log the contents of vm.member in your controller?

Comment: nothing is even logged. It looks like it is using the memberdetal controller and not the membercreate controller. I think I'm not understanding the ui-router config properly. When I put a breakpoint in membercreate it is never hit.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. `member.add` is a child to `member`. Try changing `member.add` to `memberAdd` or some such thing. That might get you back on track.

Comment: I think Mike L is right, but you'll probably also need to define an url for that state too: `url: '/memberAdd'`

Comment: yes, that's the change I make already, and it seemed to work. I guess im not fully understanding child states. It looks like it expects the child state is rendered in the parent view and I wasn't doing that, hence it was using the wrong controller.